# JTextArea in JTextPane - Want new line

Tags: java, swing, word-wrap, jtextarea, jtextpane

I want to add text to a JTextArea, and to have an auto scrollbar on vertical.

but when typing horizonally, I want an auto new line when there is no space in line..
If I use only JTextArea it's OK, but when I put it in a JScrollPane, it is not
make a new line when needed.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you have to configure the textArea to wrap:

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

You might consider reading a basic [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) to get you started effectively :-)

Answer (score 0):

By default, a `JTextArea` will not wrap text so you have to manually define that behavior:

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Also, make sure you're setting up the `JScrollPane` correctly:

```
JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(textArea);

//JScrollPanes are just like JPanels (except for the scrollbars) so be careful not to just add the JComponent to your frame; add the container instead.

frame.add(sp);
```

As a side note, read the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) @kleopatra so helpfully suggested to get a good solid base on textareas.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't JTextArea implementing the Scrollable interface? So why you need JScrollPane?

Edit to your comment, this one works for me:

```
JScrollPane sP= new JScrollPane(txtarea);
sP.setBounds(10,60,780,500);
sP.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: It is not show a scroll bar when nedded..I set autoscroll to "true"

Comment: Can you poste some code how you did put it in a JScrollPane? I edit above message with code that works for me as minimal concept

Comment: -1 for spreading random guesses (Scrollable != JScrollPane). Furtermore, setBounds is _always_ the wrong thing to do - instead use a decent LayoutManager and let that do its job